# camel body is set with request instead of response

Tags: java, logging, apache-camel

I am stuck in bit weird situation my camel route looks like this

```
 from("direct:start")
  .doTry()
      .to("http://myedpoint.com")
      .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, "com.mycompany.MyCoolRoute", " ${body}")
  .doCatch(Exception.class)
     .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, "com.mycompany.MyCoolRoute", " ${body}")
     .to("bean:foo");
```

Now what happened in my success scenario my body is logged with response I got from endpoint but in failure scenario though my endpoint is giving me failure response body is logged with my request that I have sent to end point can any please explain me why this happened and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation for the `http` component, this is expected behavior. If you look at the details for option `throwExceptionOnFailure`, it defaults to `true`, meaning that an *undesirable* status code will result in an exception being thrown and the response being tossed out. Setting this option to `false` will alter this behavior so the response is kept. [The example code in the documentation shows how this is done.](http://camel.apache.org/http.html#HTTP-UsingthrowExceptionOnFailure=falsetogetanyresponseback)